# linked library is valid in CMakeLists, but doesn't link at compile time

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, glfw

I'm just starting around with messing around with vulkan, and GLFW, but when I try to compile a test program, it gives me a bunch of linker errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/vulkan_test.dir/loops.cpp.o: in function `Loops::Init()':
loops.cpp:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
/usr/bin/ld: loops.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: loops.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: loops.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/vulkan_test.dir/loops.cpp.o: in function `Loops::Update()':
loops.cpp:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `glfwPollEvents'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/vulkan_test.dir/loops.cpp.o: in function `Loops::DeInit()':
loops.cpp:(.text+0xcd): undefined reference to `glfwDestroyWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: loops.cpp:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/vulkan_test.dir/build.make:113: vulkan_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/vulkan_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(vulkan_test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /home/headass/CMake_Modules/)

find_package(GLFW REQUIRED)
find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${VULKAN_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(vulkan_test main.cpp loops.cpp)

target_link_libraries(vulkan_test ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} ${VULKAN_LIBRARIES})
```

Any idea why this is happening? I have both vulkan and GLFW installed, `libglfw.so` is in my `/usr/lib/` directory, and clangd doesn't see anything wrong with it, but it still fails to link properly.
And yes, I *HAVE* tried googling this, to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure that variable `GLFW_LIBRARIES` **actually** contains results of `find_package(GLFW)`? According to your solution with explicit linking against `glfw`, it doesn't. The way how to extract results of `find_package(GLFW)` is determined by `FindGLFW.cmake` script which you have in your directory `/home/headass/CMake_Modules/`. Also you could examine content of the variable by simple `message("GLFW_LIBRARIES: {GLFW_LIBRARIES}")`.

Comment: I recommend using Premake (https://premake.github.io/). It's MUCH better than CMake.

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

```
target_link_libraries(vulkan_test ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} ${VULKAN_LIBRARIES})
```

to:

```
target_link_libraries(vulkan_test glfw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} ${VULKAN_LIBRARIES})
```

worked flawlessly